# DocuSign Connect - Webservice to see POST

Tags: c#, docusignapi

I'm new to DocuSign and trying to understand how Connect works in sending HTTP POST back.  I created a simple webservice to try and receive the XML POST BODY, as see below:

[Please click to see Webservice code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7ENmr.jpg)

I have my Custom Configuration "URL to Publich" pointing to where my webservice is located on my webserver. When send out an envelope, I receive the document and sign and mark as completed.  But when I look at the Connect logs, I do not see any log recorded and when I look at the Failures: I see the entry I receive an error description: https://My Webservice URL - Error - The remote server returned an error: (405) Method Not Allowed. I'm not sure what method name the post is looking for, the connect guide says a method name of "DocuSignConnectUpdate" is needed.

Can someone give me some advice or point me in the right direction as to why the POST cannot see my simple webservice? If anyone has any example as to how to catch the POST, I would really appreciate it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

For debugging in these cases, I configure my webhook configuration to use [requestb.in](http://requestb.in) It's a free service.

It will show you how the DocuSign platform is (trying) to call your listner.

You can then call your listener yourself using curl or http://hurl.it (Pretend that you are the DocuSign platform, making the POST call to your listener.)

You will probably see that either your listener is not receiving the request (firewall issue), or it's having an error while processing the request.